# Mapping a servo value (0-180) into (0-9000)

Tags: arduino

Currently I'm controlling my BLDC motor using a keypad, keying in the servo value (0-180). But my supervisor needs me to control it using a value between 0-9000 and not 0-180. I have been learning about the `map()` function. Somehow I don't quite understand and I'm currently stuck trying to incorporate it with my code. How do I map servo values of (0-180) to (0-9000)? Here is my code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);
// Set the LCD I2C address
Servo myservo;
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'}, 
  {'4', '5', '6'}, 
  {'7', '8', '9'}, 
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9, 8, 7, 6};
//row pinouts of the keypad (L1, L2, L3, L4)
byte colPins[COLS] = {5, 4, 3};
//column pinouts of the keypad (R1, R2, R3)
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
// STATE CONDITION FOR MAIN LOOP
enum  { enter_values, spin , finish } systemstate;
//FOR MOTORSPIN
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 1000;
// RPM MEASUREMENT
const int dataIN = 2; //IR sensor INPUT
unsigned long prevmillis; // To store time
unsigned long duration; // To store time difference
unsigned long lcdrefresh; // To store time for lcd to refresh
int rpm; // RPM value
boolean currentstate; // Current state of IR input scan
boolean prevstate; // State of IR sensor in previous scan
// DECLARE
int stage1speed , stage1time , stage2speed , stage2time , stage3speed , stage3time ;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(20, 4);
  myservo.attach(11);
  systemstate = enter_values;  // set up the starting state
  pinMode(dataIN, INPUT);
  prevmillis = 0;
  prevstate = LOW;
  lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
  lcd.print("SPIN COATER");
  lcd.setCursor(6, 2);
  lcd.print("MACHINE");
  delay(5000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("S = speed(sv)");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 2);
  lcd.print("T = time(sec)");
  delay(5000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("Range of Speed");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 2);
  lcd.print("0-180 sv");
  delay(5000);
  lcd.clear();
}

//FUNCTION FOR KEY IN SPEED AND TIME
void enter_speed_time() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("S=");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("T=");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("S=");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("T=");
  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
  lcd.print("S=");
  lcd.setCursor(10, 1);
  lcd.print("T=");
  lcd.setCursor(10, 2);
  lcd.print("RPM");
  stage1speed = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(2, 0);
  lcd.print(stage1speed);
  Serial.print(stage1speed);
  lcd.print("sv");
  stage1time = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
  lcd.print(stage1time);
  Serial.print(stage1time);
  lcd.print("sec");
  stage2speed = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(2, 2);
  lcd.print(stage2speed);
  Serial.print(stage2speed);
  lcd.print("sv");
  stage2time = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(2, 3);
  lcd.print(stage2time);
  Serial.print(stage2time);
  lcd.print("sec");
  stage3speed = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
  lcd.print(stage3speed);
  Serial.print(stage3speed);
  lcd.print("sv");
  stage3time = getTheNumber();
  lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
  lcd.print(stage3time);
  Serial.print(stage3time);
  lcd.print("sec");
}

// FUNCTION TO GET NUMBERS FROM 4X3 MATRIC KEYPAD
int getTheNumber() {
  char buffer[4];
  int i = 0;
  while (1) {
    char key = keypad.getKey();
    if ('0' <= key && key <= '9' && i < 3) {
      // If it's a number AND we have space left, add to our string
      buffer[i] = key;
      i++;
    } else if ('#' == key && i > 0) {
      // If it's a * or #, end
      // Null terminate
      buffer[i] = 0;
      int value = atoi(buffer);  // Convert to an integer
      break;
    }
  }
  return atoi(buffer);
}

// FUNCTION FOR RPM MEASUREMENT
void rpmMeasure() {
  // RPM Measurement
  currentstate = digitalRead(dataIN); // Read IR sensor state
  if (prevstate != currentstate) {
    // If there is change in input
    if (currentstate == HIGH) {
      // If input only changes from LOW to HIGH
      duration = (micros() - prevmillis); // Time difference between revolution in microsecond
      rpm = (60000000 / duration); // rpm = (1/ time millis)*1000*1000*60;
      prevmillis = micros(); // store time for next revolution calculation
    }
  }
  prevstate = currentstate; // store this scan (prev scan) data for next scan
  lcd.setCursor(10, 3);
  lcd.print(rpm);
}

// FUNCTION FOR MOTOR SPINNING ACCORDING TO TIME AND SPEED
void motorspin() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  int idleValue = 0;
  static enum { IDLE , STAGE0, STAGE1, STAGE2, STAGE3 } spinningstate = IDLE;
  switch (spinningstate) {
    case IDLE:
      if (key == '*') {
        Serial.print(key);
        spinningstate = STAGE0;
      }
      break;
    case STAGE0:
      myservo.write(stage1speed);
      Serial.print(stage1speed);
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      spinningstate = STAGE1;
      break;
    case STAGE1:
      if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= stage1time * interval) {
        myservo.write(stage2speed);
        Serial.print(stage2speed);
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        spinningstate = STAGE2;
      }
      break;
    case STAGE2:
      if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= stage2time * interval) {
        myservo.write(stage3speed);
        Serial.print(stage3speed);
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        spinningstate = STAGE3;
      }
      break;
    case STAGE3:
      if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= stage3time * interval) {
        myservo.write(idleValue);
        Serial.print(idleValue);
        spinningstate = IDLE;
      }
      break;
    default:
      spinningstate = IDLE;
      break;
  }
}

// MAIN LOOP
void loop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  switch (systemstate) {
    case enter_values:
      enter_speed_time();
      systemstate = spin;
      break;
    case spin:
      rpmMeasure();
      motorspin();
      if (key == '#') {
        Serial.print(key);
        systemstate = finish;
      }
      break;
    case finish:
      lcd.clear();
      delay(1000);
      systemstate = enter_values;
      break;
    default:
      systemstate = enter_values;
  }
  delay(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to convert value from 0-180 to 0-9000

```
map(value,0,180,0,9000)
```

to convert from 0-9000 to 0-180

```
map(value,0,9000,0,180)
```

Comment: if stage1speed in in <0,9000> myservo.write(map(stage1speed,0,9000,0,180));